# Why People have skin color between fair and dark?

Tags: genetics

According to Mendel's laws traits do not show any blending. So according to his laws people only with fair or dark skin should exist. Do the alleles in this case blend? And why?

Comment: There are several traits that do not follow the simplistic Mendelian rules. With skin colour, the trait is actually polygenic (and also quantitative).

Comment: Mendel also fudged his data. Traits blend all the time.

Comment: this question has been well addressed here: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34565/skin-color-explanation
( so I guess it might be marked as duplicate ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mendel's laws were very basic to aid in the comprehension of genetics.  You think of Mendel's genes as an `+-` pair where `+` is dominant and `-` is recessive, making our `+-` gene produce offspring with the `+` trait but still being a carrier of the `-` trait.

However, when it comes skin colour, eye colour, hair colour, height, tendency to muscle growth, and a thousand other things, the gene is more like a series of `++-++-+++-`, `+` is more recessive than `-`, but some of `+` will still show up over `-`.

In short, the colour of a person's skin is not a simple `+-` gene of dark and fair; everyone carries a certain amount of `pigment` genes and certain number of `non-pigment` genes.  The amount that one carries of each of the genes will determine his skin colour **and** his/her ability to pass on the dark/light characteristic.

Comment: To give a basic idea about the dimensions: if I remember correctly, from genome-wide association studies, height is currently known to be influenced by approx. 500 genes - that is 2-3% of all approx. 20000 protein-coding genes. However, studying these loci explain only about 20% of the variation seen in the phenotype height.

Comment: A minor suggestion: Instead of X and Y use some other symbols. X and Y can be confused for chromosomes.

Comment: Good point, @WYSIWYG .  Hadn't thought of that.